# How to add markdown formatting to photo caption using Telegraf (Telegram Bot Framework for Node.js)

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot, telegraf

I'm using [Telegraf](https://telegraf.js.org/) to build a Node.js Telegram bot.

When I try to send a photo I use:

```js
const bot = new Telegraf(process.env.BOT_TOKEN);
bot.on('text', (ctx) => ctx.replyWithPhoto(
  { url: 'https://i.picsum.photos/id/237/200/300.jpg' },
  { caption: 'This is *Bobby*!' }
));
bot.launch();
```

The resulting message includes the photo along with a plain text caption:

> This is *Bobby*!

How do I make the caption to look formatted with markdown? Like this:

> This is **Bobby**!

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to supply [`parse_mode`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendphoto) in your second parameter. Possible options currently are `html`, `Markdown` and `MarkdownV2` (for more details, see [here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#formatting-options)).

In your example, this would be:

```js
bot.on('text', (ctx) => ctx.replyWithPhoto(
  { url: 'https://i.picsum.photos/id/237/200/300.jpg' },
  {
    caption: 'This is *Bobby*!',
    parse_mode: 'MarkdownV2'
  }
));
```

Comment: how to escape parenthesis and other info?