# Telegram Post Message with URL

Tags: python, telegram

I'm using the most simple way to interact with bot in Python.
By HTTP requests! I'm newby in this area and reading on internet I've become more confused.

This is my setting:

```py
import requests
msg = "This is the message\:\n I'm using also special char so I have to use \\ to escape special char"
requests.post('https://api.telegram.org/API_TOKEN/sendMessage?chat_id=CHAT_ID&parse_mode=MarkdownV2&text='+msg)
```

Now the problem is that I want to insert a link in the message with a clickable test that mask the URL.

I've found in the docs:

```py
[example text](http://www.example.com)
```

And I have tired to append this string to message but it doesn't work.

If I try to send the link alone it works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add markdown formatting to photo caption using Telegraf (Telegram Bot Framework for Node.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62097100/how-to-add-markdown-formatting-to-photo-caption-using-telegraf-telegram-bot-fra) (That question covers Node.js but the answer is pretty much the same since the Bot API doesn't care which language you use …)

Answer (score 0):

use urllib library to do this.

```
import urllib
msg = urllib.parse.quote_plus(<YOUR STRING INCLUDING THE LINK>)
urllib.request.urlopen(f"https://api.telegram.org/bot<BOT TOKEN>/sendMessage?chat_id=<CHAT ID>&text={msg}")
```